# How to enable multiple traceflags

Tags: sql-server, dbcc

I want to enable trace flags 4199, 8024, 9024, 1236 & 1117 on SQL SERVER (Startup Parameters).

I went to SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server ("instance_name"), and then clicked Properties -> Startup Parameters tab -> and I  added -T4199 -T8024 -T9024 -T1236 -T1117 separately.

This is a SQL Server 2016 instance.

[image: Restarted After this]

[image: used dbcc tracestatus(-1)]

[image]

Comment: Add them one by one. Or use Powershell: http://www.erichumphrey.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Add-SqlServerStartupParameter.ps1

Comment: I tried, but still the trace were not enabled...Also i want to ask if DBCC TRACEON(T4199 , -1) or adding -T4199 to startup parameter both are same ??

Comment: DBCC TRACEON(4199) enables the trace flag for a single session. DBCC TRACEON(4199, -1) enables the trace flag globally, in all sessions. Adding the startup parameter has a permanent effect, but requires a service restart.

Comment: so is both same adding in startup or using dbcc traceon(4199,-1)

Comment: dbcc traceon(4199,-1) would be in effect globally 'until server restart'.  Adding trace flags to the startup parameters ensures they remain in effect after server restarts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try add each trace flag separately.
[image: multiple trace flags]

Some trace flags are now build in, in SQL Server 2016 like TF 1117, TF 1236 only applies to SQL 2012 and 2014 without SP1, TF 4199 is now default as is TF 8024.

For the complete list of trace flags go to this url: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188396.aspx

Comment: I added them seprately and restarted the service...but when i used DBCC TRACESTATUS() its showing value as 0

Comment: Execute DBCC TRACESTATUS(-1)

Comment: Still it shows status as 0

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of the parameters like I did in the answer?

Comment: i have added screen shot plese look into it..the status still shows 0

Comment: Just to be sure, you did restart the SQL Server service after you added the parameters, didn't you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45356/discussion-between-sqlstad-and-joeprince).